# Joining two rows into one rows (different column) in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table with values like this

```
ID   |Name     |Balance     |Type   |ProductName
1     Abdol     10000        1       RAID100
2     HIVE      5000000      2       RAID100
3     Ade       20000        1       RAID200
4     Koi       30000        1       RAID100
```

I want to re-arrange the table using select script to:

```
ProductName | Balance_Type_1 | Balance_Type_2
RAID100       40000            5000000
RAID200       20000            0
```

I've tried nested case when, but it always create one column with Product-name followed by 0 value besides and repeated.

Thank You

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want aggregation :

```
select productname, 
       sum(case when type = 1 then balance else 0 end) as balance_type1,
       sum(case when type = 2 then balance else 0 end) as balance_type2
from table t
group by productname;
```

Run the aggregation query whenever is needed, do not create summary table structure in the database. It will be difficult to manage.

Comment: I've tried with that, and the result still same, and always show table like:
ProductName | Balance_Type_1 | Balance_Type_1
RAID100           40000                    0
RAID100           0                            5000000
RAID200           20000                    0

Comment: I've run this query with your data and I get the exact result shown in your expected output. If you have the group by productname as shown then it is not possible for you to have the RAID100 listed twice as in your comment.

Comment: im sorry that was my mistake, i including [type] and [balance] in my group by.
After i removed it, the query show what i expected before.
Thanks for everyone :)

Answer (score 1):

One option would be using [`pivot`](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/pivot-and-unpivot-operators-11gr1) provided you database has version 11g+ :

```
select ProductName , 
       sum(nvl(Balance_Type_1,0)) as Balance_Type_1,
       sum(nvl(Balance_Type_2,0)) as Balance_Type_2
  from t
  pivot
  (
   sum( Balance ) for Type in ( 1 as Balance_Type_1, 2 as Balance_Type_2  )
  )
 group by ProductName;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=d97a490f957a81dd842369078e7d2b9a)</kbd>